# Font Identification

Tags: fonts, document-classes, preamble

Can anyone identify the font that is used in [this article?](http://www.mit.edu/~mrognlie/piketty_diminishing_returns.pdf)

Furthermore, is this font compatible with the 'article' class?

Note: Using CTRL+D within Adobe Acrobat presents a number of fonts the document uses, which while narrowing it down, still leaves the question unanswered.

Comment: The font is Palatino, and the LaTeX clone of it can be accessed using the `mathpazo` package. This package is useable in most if not all document classes.

Comment: @AlanMunn Excellent, that's it. Many thanks. If you want to provide this as an answer, I will gratefully accept.